# Save HTML Form Data To Database - Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I want to update database values by HTML Forms

**HTML form :**

```
<form action="/school_manager/students/{{student.id}}/update/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="update_name">Edit Name :</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="update_name" id="update_name" placeholder="Enter A Name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

**views.py :**

```
def update_student_detail(request, student_id):
   list = get_object_or_404 ( student, pk=student_id)
   if request.method == 'POST' :
       student.First_Name = request.POST.get('update_name','')
   list.save()
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/school_manager/students/' + student_id)
```

When I run the program and type a word in text box, after submit it does not work. I can't see any change to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my fault
in `views.py` calling **student** for change database values is wrong

When we created a list of database tuple, values can edit by using that list

```
def update_student_detail(request, student_id):
   list = get_object_or_404 ( student, pk=student_id)
   if request.method == 'POST' :
      list.First_Name = request.POST.get('update_name','')
   list.save()
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/school_manager/students/' + student_id)
```